# How to find latest record from hive?

Tags: hive

We have a table in Hive containing location and name of employee.

In the next update of table, the location of employee is changed.

Both the ORC files are present in Hive Metastore location.
Now, how to trigger the select query to get the latest location of the employee?

Comment: Are you storing the insert or the last updated timestamp in employee table?

Comment: No,  not adding the timestamp.

Comment: Once the update is done, will the table not contain the latest location?

Comment: Hive does not support update operation. It creates 1 more file in Hive metastore location. So whenever, I am triggering the SELECT query, it fetches both the records. adding the timestamp is the last option, if nothing else work.